# Backbone.js why do I have to use underscore (_.each) to target the model?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, underscore.js

So whenever I want to select a model from my collection I always use backbone's very own `where` method.

```
var homeTeam = this.collection.where({teamName: this.currentTeamName('home')});
```

I have my own method that grabs the current team and I pass "home" or "away" as an argument, and it knows which model to grab, this is all fine and dandy, another example would be to just pass a string like below.

```
// This is practically the same as the above.
var homeTeam = this.collection.where({teamName: 'bulls'});
```

So if I log that variable `console.log(homeTeam)` the console shows that model, just like it does any model.

The console shows me I have access to regular methods a model can use http://backbonejs.org/#Model but if I call one of those methods I get an error, ex `homeTeam.save({someAttr: 'juicy'});`

So I just use underscore's `each` method like below, and it works.

```
_.each(homeTeam, function(model) { model.save({someAttr: 'juicy'}); }, this);
```

I have been doing this for awhile but I am curious to know why I must do that, when logging the `homeTeam` it passes the model just like

```
_.each(homeTeam, function(model) { console.log(model) }, this);
```

they show up exactly the same in the console.

Comment: What's the error you get when trying to directly call .save ?

Comment: You guys are all right, it makes sense now that it returns as an array. Let me play around with `findWhere` and dig in brb, you guys are awesome.

Answer (score 1):

Because `where` returns an **array** of models. The array is not a **model** object. It's an array.

See [source](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-where).

Answer (score 1):

Ahh, I think I see the problem here.

.where returns an Array; Even though it's an array of Model, the Javascript console will evaluate the entry as a model so you can see the methods that Backbone provides.

What you need to do is use .findWhere.

This will return the first matching model, as a correctly typed object.

Alternately you could try (just to prove) 'homeTeam[0].save(...)

To clarify: you're getting the error because homeTeam is not what you think it is; welcome to Javascript!

Comment: Yeah this makes sense, really this is all I need. Thanks let me play around brb.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `team.teamName` is unique you could safely use `.findWhere`, which returns a single model from your collection instead of `.find`, which returns an array of models.

From the [underscore docs](http://underscorejs.org/#findWhere):

> **`findWhere`**
>   Looks through the list and returns the **first value** that matches all of the key-value pairs listed in properties.

as opposed to

> **`where`**
>   Looks through each value in the list, **returning an array** of all the values that contain all of the key-value pairs listed in properties.